# Error creating subnet in aws_vpc with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-vpc

Everything seems right. What am I missing?

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
region = "us-east-1"
access_key = "---"
secret_key = "---"
}

resource "aws_instance" "MyWinServer"  {
ami = "ami-085d15593174f2582"
instance_type = "t2.micro"
tags = { Name = "WinServer"  }
}
resource "aws_vpc" "MyVpc" {
cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
tags = { Name = "WinVpc"  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "MySubnet" {
vpc_id = "aws_vpc.MyVpc.id"
cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

> terraform apply
```

> ...
> │ Error: error creating EC2 Subnet: InvalidVpcID.NotFound: The vpc ID 'aws_vpc.MyVpc.id' does not exist
> │       status code: 400, request id: 2d384c58-2d02-4761-bcd2-1044a464a844
> │
> │   with aws_subnet.MySubnet,
> │   on main.tf line 26, in resource "aws_subnet" "MySubnet":
> │   26: resource "aws_subnet" "MySubnet" {

Everything seems right. What am I missing?

Comment: Please remove the quotes from the `vpc_id` in the `aws_subnet` resource. Correctly should be something like: `vpc_id = aws_vpc.MyVpc.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting comment as an answer. You have incorrect referencing for `vpc_id` in resource `aws_subnet`. You don't need string representation for `vpc_id`.

The correct code would be as follows.

```
resource "aws_instance" "MyWinServer" {
  ami           = "ami-085d15593174f2582"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  tags          = { Name = "WinServer" }
}
resource "aws_vpc" "MyVpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  tags       = { Name = "WinVpc" }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "MySubnet" {
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.MyVpc.id ## Correction ## 
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```